# Creating a C++ Multifunction Calculator

Tags: c++, input, calculator

So, after two and a half weeks of progressively programming a nested switch calculator for a future University of Michigan application, I have come to the climax of new ideas and creations for this calculator.  It is a C++, control-prompt ran nested switch calculator; prompting users to enter 'A-P' at the main menu for the type of calculation (Calculus, Trig, Business, etc.), with switches inside for each, including various inclusions and subsections of each process.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QTPE.png        --MY CURRENT PROJECT

**So, my next step/problem.**

I have yet to find out how I can combine all these into a smart, concise and accurate calculator that takes TEXT INPUT, and calculates it right then and there with the given operators, evidently given by the users.  Does anyone have any clue on how to accomplish this?  What I can look into to completely change this calculator into something similar to Wolfram Alpha™ (the GOOGLE for calculations).

It would look something like this:

```
       Enter your calculation here:_____________________________________
```

The user would enter anything ranging from quadratic formulas to just simple addition.  Seems like a very tough concept to grasp given that C++ isnt very inclined to create Applets like Java, and also that I am fairly new to programming (about 1 month strong).

If anyone has any clue on how I can accomplish this (if it is even possible), that would be amazing.  Thank you!

Comment: So your question is *"How to parse math expressions with C++?"*? Your problem as stated lies somewhere between nearly trivial and nearly impossible for a single person.

Comment: Look at the MATLAB or octave source code for inspiration as well as the Boost math libraries.

Comment: Take a college-level course on compiler design and implementation. Learn all that there is to learn about lexical analysis, grammar parsing, LALR(1) parsing, and recursive-descent parsing. Then, armed with this knowledge, writing a parser for arithmetical expression should be a piece of cake.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you must tell us more precisely what your program must support. Parsing normal arithmetic stuff like `+-*/()` is fairly easy, if you want to solve integrals and differential equations and all that good jazz Mathematica can do you need to come up with a syntax first. I doubt that would work out too well.

Comment: I agree with everything that the folks above have said, however with the right libraries this becomes a tractable problem even for someone who is totally new to this. Having used Lex and Yacc before for your exact problem, I recommend those as a starting place. Here's a tutorial page for building a basic calculator with them http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/